# Detect presence of nearby devices android

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-nearby

A part of an app I am trying to implement involves detecting nearby Android devices using the same app. The use case is something like this, assuming we have devices A and B getting into contact:

- if the devices are close to each other (Bluetooth range close), a message will be displayed on both devices: A saying it detected B, B saying it detected A
- if the two devices lose connection to each other, a message should be displayed as well on both devices: A saying it lost connection to B, B saying it lost connection to A
- if they come into contact again during the same running of the app, they should reconnect

I tried using both Google Nearby API and Google Nearby Messages API, but I keep having problems with them.

Would you recommend one option so I could focus on that one?

Comment: Hey you need to tell what is the problem that you are facing. Just as a side note, Google Nearby Message API uses Bluetooth, BLE and Wi-Fi to establish communication between the devices. BLE broadcast is not supported on some old devices. Both devices needs to be connected to internet (not necessarily same network) and on both devices the apps that are hosting the API should have the same APP KEY

Comment: Hi, yes, both devices are connected to the internet and have the same com.google.android.nearby.messages.API_KEY. I am not able to detect when the two devices can no longer "see" each other. Also, I tried making both devices a publisher and a subscriber in the same time, does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah it's perfectly OK to make both devices publisher and subscriber. We have implemented something similar (but each device is either a publisher or subscriber at one instance not both) using Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) where you can listen for callbacks when the devices are close by and can detect other and when a detected device moves away. Anyways I have put an answer (too long to fit in comment). Check if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

I seriously recommend that you stop adopting Bluetooth and google-nearby api to help you in that matter. It would be better if you switch to Socket Programming instead. It actually allows you to detect all the devices that are connected to a single WiFi Network. So lets say for example, you have your own Socket Protocols that are running the show, then you can easily manage the task. Consider employing a DatagramSocket and a DatagramPacket strategy in this matter. So lets say you have a few Devices, A,B,C,D

1. Device A,B,C,D establish a DatagramSocket internally and start listening for DatagramPackets on specific IP Address and a specific port
2. So once you establish a [DatagramSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) on Device A,B,C,D, you will know the IP Address and Port Number of the DatagramSocket running independently on the devices
3. Eventually you can allow Device A,B,C,D to share data between them by using [DatagramPacket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html)

I have actually implemented this idea, and if you are looking further in this area, then please do let us know

Comment: What if my devices aren't in the same WiFi network? They are both connected to the internet, but not via WiFI

Comment: Then given that the IP Address that the Sockets will bind to are STATIC, then maybe there is a clear solution to the problem. Otherwise it's just another RENT-A-WEBSERVER problem.

Answer (score -1):

When using the Google Nearby Message API, a subscriber can always know when it has lost the connectivity with a publisher. Have a look at this sample code from Google docs

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            Log.d(TAG, "Found message: " + messageAsString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            Log.d(TAG, "Lost sight of message: " + messageAsString);
        }
    }
}
```

Ref - https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/pub-sub

Comment: Hi, that's where I also got my inspiration from. Somehow I couldn't make it work properly. When I was using only the Google Nearby API, I couldn't make the publisher reconnect to its subscribers after losing connection to internet. I will further research on this direction with Google Nearby Messages API though and try to find a solution. If you are familiar with iOS, what I am trying to do is accomplish something similar to what the GameKit Sensor is doing https://developer.apple.com/reference/gamekit/gksession